# Monkey-patching a named function that's called immediately

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

A script I'm loading is misbehaving. It's got a structure like this:

```
function bad_function() {
    ...
}

/* randomly generated stuff */

bad_function();
```

How do I modify the behavior of `bad_function` if it's called immediately at the end of the script? I thought of creating a silently read-only property on `window` before loading the script, but this throws a `TypeError: Identifier 'bad_function' has already been declared` exception when the above script is executed:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'bad_function', {
    value: function() {
        /* my monkey-patched code */
    }
});
```

How do I monkey-patch this function?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Is it a browser specific issue you are facing?

Comment: @jjk_charles: Nope, it's browser-agnostic and is an issue with the script.

Comment: Are you using "defineProperty" in the same JS file as the original bad_function(), Or are they in different files? If different files, in what order is the <script> tag placed?

Comment: @jjk_charles: I can't modify the script which contains `bad_function`, but I can modify the page that loads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't an answer to my question in general, I was able to monkey patch my specific function by patching a global function like `encodeURIComponent` that was called inside of my function, performing the necessary changes, and throwing an exception to prevent the rest of the original function from running.

```
var old_encodeURIComponent = window.encodeURIComponent;

window.encodeURIComponent = function() {
    // If this function is used in multiple places, look for variables in
    // the current scope to determine if this is the right spot to start 
    // monkey patching.
    if (typeof a === 'undefined' || typeof b === 'undefined') {
        return old_encodeURIComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // You now have access to the variables in the scope of your target 
    // function. If your monkey patching is just a simple tweak, you're all set

    // Otherwise, do what you need to do and throw an exception to stop the
    // rest of the code from running

    throw 'goodbye';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not nice, but all I can think to do is to load the script via ajax instead of putting it in a `<script>` tag, manipulate the result string to call your own version of the function (or "rename" `bad_function` so it doesn't override your version), then put *that* in a `<script>` tag and append it to your page:

An example using jQuery for simplicity:

```
function good_function() {
    alert("I am good");
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        html: "function bad_function() { alert('hahaha'); } bad_function();",
        delay: 0
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        // comment this line to see the original
        data = data.replace('bad_function();', 'good_function();')

        var newScript = $('<script type="text/javascript" />').text(data);
        $('body').append(newScript);
    }
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8otjam/)

Comment: Renaming `bad_function` would defeat the whole point of monkey patching.